# Mac mini 4,1 only shows 1 CPU

Tags: 10.10, mac, apple

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop x86_64 on a Mac mini 4.1 and it looks like I can only use one CPU core. It looks like the kernel supports SMP. I wish I could tell you whether it worked with Lucid, but I didn't notice.

Anybody know why this isn't working?

Here's some relevant output:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
Macmini4,1

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"

$ uname -a
Linux harold 2.6.35-22-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 20:45:36 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT:** I should have included `/proc/cpuinfo`. This is what I used to confirm that I was only getting use out of one core. I've since performed a fresh install of x86 Maverick on the Mac mini (which was an exercise in frustration in itself) and now I have use of both cores. I never figured out why it didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mac needs the grub-efi installed (with rEFIt), otherwise ubuntu starts with bios and then cannot recognize more than one core

Comment: Initially, I booted directly from the CD and installed an MBR partition table and did not use rEFIt at all. I've been using it and successfully recognizing all cores for a few months now, but I first reinstalled OS X, repartitioned with Bootcamp, installed rEFIt, then installed Ubuntu and now I boot Ubuntu from the rEFIt menu.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you only have 1 CPU then you should only see one CPU. Seeing two cores is something you normally see in `/proc/cpuinfo` but this doesn't have to be the case.

Some Intel machines have bios settings for switching on the extra core duo core being treated like a separate cpu. For the mac it's probably not an issue. Can you test to make sure your computer is not using the second core and post the results of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` into your question.

Comment: I've never seen multi-core CPUs presented in Linux in any way other than as multiple CPUs. Your answer also does not relate to my question, which pertains *specifically* to the interaction between Ubuntu Maverick and a Mac mini 4,1.

Comment: Then your question was ambiguous. Probably a kernel hicup

Comment: My question was **not** ambiguous. The title of the question says "Mac mini 4,1" and it's tagged 10.10. And "kernel hicup?" What does that even mean? And this "hicup" persists between reboots?

Comment: yes. it's a hicup that was persistent.